# FreeTDS hangs indefinitely after Microsoft SQL Express 2012 Install

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, freetds

FreeTDS hangs indefinitely when I try to connect to a server:

```
C:\FreeTDS\bin>tsql -H localhost -p 1433
locale is "English_United States.1252"
locale charset is "CP1252"
using default charset "CP1252"

(nothing else is displayed, can only exit with ^C)
```

Identical behaviour occurs when I run `tsql -S <servername>`.

I recently uninstalled Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, and then installed the Express edition. Connection with `tsql -H localhost -p 1433` worked before the uninstall/install.

Running `tsql -C` yields:

```
Compile-time settings (established with the "configure" script)
                        Version: freetds v0.91.98
         freetds.conf directory: /mingw/etc
 MS db-lib source compatibility: no
    Sybase binary compatibility: no
                  Thread safety: yes
                  iconv library: yes
                    TDS version: 7.0
                          iODBC: no
                       unixodbc: yes
          SSPI "trusted" logins: yes
                       Kerberos: yes (Heimdal 1.5.3)
                 SSL encryption: yes (OpenSSL 1.0.1e)
```

**Some more information:**

I have the folowing SQL-related services running:

- SQL Full-Text Filter Daemon Launcher (SQLEXPRESS)
- SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)
- SQL Server Browser
- SQL Server Reporting Services (SQLEXPRESS)
- SQL Server VSS Writer

I have tried reinstalling FreeTDS.

I have enabled TCP/IP for SQLEXPRESS in the Sql Server Configuration Manager.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `tsql` command was hanging because the server was not running on the default port. I found this out by running `C:\>netstat -na | find "1433"`, which showed nothing LISTENING on port 1433.

This is how I fixed the problem:

1. Open "Sql Server Configuration Manager"
2. Go to "SQL Server Network Configuration > Protocols for *SERVER*"
3. Right click "TCP/IP", select "Properties", go to the "IP Addresses" tab
4. Under "IPAll" set "TCP Port" to the desired port number
5. Click OK, and restart the SQL Server service.

[image: TCP Port was previously blank, setting it to a valid port solved the problem.]