# Where is FreeTDS installed when I download pymssql on windows?

Tags: python, freetds, pymssql

I am having trouble connecting pymssql to my local instance of MSSQL, and would like to use the `tsql` debugging command that is included with FreeTDS. However, I am unable to find where it FreeTDS is installed. As far as I know, it comes pre-compiled with pymssql on windows, I just don't know where it is.

More info:

- I am using windows
- I am not using a virtual environment
- I used the [package manager included with PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html) to install pymssql (I assume it wraps `pip`)

Comment: Sorry to answer a question to a question, but are you connecting to SQL Server or Access? If you are, why not just use MS's SQL drivers since you're on Windows?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server. It's because I'm using pymssql to connect. If this doesn't work I may use pypyodbc insted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AKAIK, pymssql for Windows doesn't come bundled with FreeTDS. If anything, IIRC, it uses the Windows SQL Server driver. To use FreeTDS instead, you'd have to download and install it:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/freetdswindows/

By default, the latest version will install to c:\freetds-0.95rc2

Please see my above comment as well. I'll amend this answer if necessary with more information. Good luck!

UPDATE:

You can connect to SQL Server if you're on Windows using the native drive through pyodbc like this:

```
DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=yourserver;PORT=1433;DATABASE=yourdb;UID=dbuser;PWD=dbpassword
```

You may have better luck with that if the FreeTDS installation doesn't work for you.

Comment: Between your answer and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29310336/freetds-hangs-indefinitely-after-microsoft-sql-express-2012-install), my problem is fixed. Thank you.

Comment: just switching to pyodbc made my life easier