# Python 3.4 - Sybase ASE connection

Tags: python, database-connection, python-3.4, sap-ase

I would like to connect to a Sybase Ase 15 db with Python. Unfortunately I couldnt find any working solution for Windows with Python 3.4. Could anyone refer something? I tried with a few without luck. Can I use OleDb driver (dll) maybe somehow?
It would be great something free which is updated recently. I found solutions from 2012, but there werent working either.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use pyodbc:

```
import pyodbc

DbConnection = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=freetds;SERVER=%s;PORT=%s;UID=%s;PWD=%s;DATABASE=%s;TDS _Version=5.0;' % (self.ServerAddress, self.ServerPort,
'aselogin', 'loginpwd', DefaultDb),unicode_results=True,autocommit=True)
```

Prerequisite: installing the driver FreeTDS corresponding to your OS.

Comment: I installed pyodbc, set the the settings for the db. It says no default driver specified. I tried to install freetds without luck yet. (Windows so it is not too straightforward). Thank you.

Comment: You are right. This config requires to have the driver Freetds. On Solaris, we have the package CSWfreetds installed. It's coming from http://www.freetds.org. I updated my answer.

Comment: Any idea for Windows? Unfortunately I couldn`t succeed with that.
The closest was the original Sybase pack.
Sybase.connect(...)
It says ct_connect(): directory service layer: internal directory control layer error: Requested server name not found.
Manually I could connect to this server with the same settings.

Comment: freetds for windows : http://sourceforge.net/projects/freetdswindows/. Freetds can be used for Sybase ASE and MS SQL. And there is more webpages about MS SQL like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31350956/where-is-freetds-installed-when-i-download-pymssql-on-windows

Comment: I tried to install it, however it is not clear how Python finds the Freetds driver.

Comment: have you tried to define an ODBC DSN called for example "ASEPYTHON" in Windows then connect to the db with : DbConnection = pyodbc.connect("DSN=ASEPYTHON")

Comment: Yes, I could finally. Are there any ways to export DSN from Windows? Thank you so much.

Comment: it seems to depend if you use file DSN or system DSN: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0eab7303-8995-4d33-8fa4-125a67bd9c5a/how-do-i-import-my-old-odbc-settings?forum=sqldataaccess

Answer (score 0):

First of all I want to point out the following: **we can't connect to the Sybase ASE database just using Python**; we have to use an external binary (called driver) which is able to manage the connections. In my case, I connect from a Windows machine using **"jconn4.jar" driver**.

In order to get the driver (jconn4.jar) I had to install Dbeaver application., and I set up a connection to the Sybase database that I want to access via python.

[image: Create Sybase Connection from dBeaver]

The next step is to test the connection and get the connection parameters. **Press Test Connection --> Details**.
In the windows that popped up we have all the details we need to configure the Sybase connection from python.

```
import jaydebeapi

server = "<server IP>"
username = "<username>"
password = "<password>"
database = "<datamase/schema>"
port = <port>
jdbc_driver = r'..\DBeaverData\drivers\drivers\sybase\jconnect\jconn4.jar'  // this is the driver path; the path is obtained from the details window

conn = jaydebeapi.connect('com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver', f'jdbc:sybase:Tds:{server}:{port}/{database}', {'user': username, 'password': password},
                          jdbc_driver)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from my_table")
result = cursor.fetchall()
print(result)
```

**If you get an error, regarding "JAVA_HOME" is missing**

1. Check JDK is installed on your machine (I have installed JDK 1.8.0_202)
   --> If not; install JDK
2. Add java path to the Environment Variables --> System Variables --> Path --> Edit --> New and paste the path to the Java bin folder (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin) --> Press OK
3. Specify the JAVA_HOME environment variable; Environment Variables --> System Variables --> New --> Varialbe Name: JAVA_HOME, Varialbe Value: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202